# Trying to install filosottile/musl-cross/musl-cross on m1 macbook

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, apple-m1

I`m trying to install filosottile/musl-cross/musl-cross via brew and facing an error at this stage:

```
==> /opt/homebrew/opt/make/bin/gmake install TARGET=x86_64-linux-musl
Last 15 lines from /Users/galshalom/Library/Logs/Homebrew/musl-cross/01.gmake:
  "_host_hooks", referenced from:
      gt_pch_save(__sFILE*) in libbackend.a(ggc-common.o)
      gt_pch_restore(__sFILE*) in libbackend.a(ggc-common.o)
      toplev::main(int, char**) in libbackend.a(toplev.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[3]: *** [../../src_gcc/gcc/lto/Make-lang.in:81: lto1] Error 1
gmake[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rm gcc.pod
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/private/tmp/musl-cross-20210510-41370-xpfsk6/musl-cross-make-0.9.9/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_gcc/gcc'
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:4361: all-gcc] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/private/tmp/musl-cross-20210510-41370-xpfsk6/musl-cross-make-0.9.9/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl/obj_gcc'
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:222: obj_gcc/gcc/.lc_built] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/private/tmp/musl-cross-20210510-41370-xpfsk6/musl-cross-make-0.9.9/build/local/x86_64-linux-musl'
gmake: *** [Makefile:183: install] Error 2
```

Cant find appropriate solution on web.

Answer (score 0):

brew edit musl-cross

patch do # Apple Silicon build fix for gcc-10.3.0 and below

url "https://github.com/richfelker/musl-cross-make/commit/3dd050fa.patch?full_index=1"

sha256 "6ecb5d306b2307e058ec0538862bbddec9fcb7a1c4f9cae5c55d29fb39dc34d8"

end

brew reinstall musl-cross

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).